# Define a variable in Bash or Perl with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, perl, date

I have a file that has some lines like this:

`{"v":0,"_id":"54ff561168a","time":"1421165205"}`

I want to use bash that read each line and set the value of the time as `Variable` (t) and replace it with other timestamp using `date -d @{$t}`

Do you know how can I use regular expression for getting the value of time as variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm). You can parse JSON in perl like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper; 

my $text = '{"v":0,"_id":"54ff561168a","time":"1421165205"}';

my $data = decode_json ( $text );
print Dumper $data;

print $data -> {"time"},"\n";

$data -> {"time"} = time();

$text = encode_json($data);

print "Result:\n";
print $text;
```

You don't need regular expressions - and indeed, you should actively avoid them, because `JSON` allows you to format your data with e.g. line feeds/indentation - and is semantically identical.

E.g you could output your example above as:

```
{
   "_id" : "54ff561168a",
   "time" : 1433859139,
   "v" : 0
}
```

By using:

```
$text = to_json($data, {pretty => 1});
```

It means the same thing, but different regular expressions apply thanks to changing whitespace etc.

If you wish to manipulate/reformat your timestamp, I'll refer you to the excellent [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module:

```
use Time::Piece;
my $t = localtime ( $data -> {"time"} );
print $t;
```

Will give:

```
Tue Jan 13 16:06:45 2015
```

If you want a specific format:

```
print $t->strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"),"\n";
```

Giving:

```
2015/01/13 16:06:45
```